# Rails: How to artificially specify param key/value values through the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to trigger an action of a particular website. However, it is supposed to handle params with certain key/value pairs (`params = {:cost => 5, :state => "NY"}`). Would there be a way to specify these params values in the URL? How would I provide these key/values otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show_things_path(:cost => 5, :state => "NY")
```

will add those key/values to params.

Edit:

for a string URL

```
"/show_things?cost=5&state='NY'"
```

Comment: the thing is this site is live. I am not adding to the views. I have to actually trigger the controller/action in a browser.

Comment: so `www.mysite.com/controller/action?cost=5&state='NY'` would work?

Comment: Yes.  Try and double check.  The URL should only be `/controller/action?cost=5&state='NY'`